# What is the visualization technology behind cartoDB?

Tags: carto

What is the technology behind cartoDB visualization, does it use MapServer, GeoServer, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components are documented in https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/README.md and answer to your question is Mapnik.